# Unity for android (non-game) development?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have some experience in Python and know that Kivy is a good platform to create python android apps. Though as side hobby, I am learning c#/unity for indie game development, I know unity is good for developing android game, but let's say I want to build a weather app on android, does unity have the capability to allow developers to do so?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Unity has the capability to create non-game applications for Android (and iOS). However, I would highly discourage it. Using Unity for non-game development is like building a house out of sheet metal. While it can be done, it's not the right tool for the job and anyone who sees it can tell.

Comment: Thanks, just for understanding purposes, what are the major things missing in Unity than are present in say Kivy? Also am I wrong putting this question here? I thought of putting it in game section but thought it wasn't game-related either.

Comment: It was down voted because of #4 http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic I would guess.

Comment: Well Stackoverflow is more for solving programming problems, not answering subjective questions. As par of Unity it's not something that is "missing" but more of like trying to nail something with a screwdriver. You can do it but it's not the right tool for the right project

Comment: I see, thanks for the constructive feedback,  and apologize for my ignorance,  I wonder if I have similar broad topic questions in the future, should I avoid stackoverflow altogether and ask on other sites like Quora instead?

Comment: Yes, you should ask on other sites.  try answers.unity3d.com for example if it is unity related.